# Is there a shorthand way to save a sharepoint list as csv

Tags: excel, sharepoint-list, export-to-excel

With Google sheets one can save a (single) tab from the sheet as csv by adding `?format.csv` to the document url. Is there a similar way for sharepoint lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**As a short answer:** No.

There is no such parameter to export a list or Library to Excel / CSV from URL.

---

Behind clicking on **Export List to Excel** from the above ribbon, you will get a URL like

```
http://your site /_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={638D72C3-264C-4797-9812-67544942EFEB}
```

This link requires at least the `List ID`, and when you browse this URL in IE browser, a file with `*.iqy` extension will be downloaded as shown below.

[image]

This file can be opened by Excel after converting its contents to a table as shown below.

[image]

---

In fact, I don't think this URL will be helpful by any means like google sheet.

Therefore, the simplest way is using `Export to Excel`, then open the exported file with Excel and finally, save it as `CSV`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I sort of found